# Set environment variable in unix machine using bash script via YAML steps

Tags: linux, bash, unix, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to set the below environment variable to a Unix machine through bash script as an inline script in the YAML file

My env variables are

```
cache=30
delay=10
url={"https.8shd3dad#d/wipeout@doamin.com"}
```

I have tried the below steps in YAML for setting the same, but couldn't see the environment variable and its value at my runtime

```
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: export cache=30
               export url={"https.8shd3dad#d/wipeout@doamin.com"}
               export Delay=10
    env:
       cache : $(30)
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue? since I am new to YAML and bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each `export` command, you also need to set the variable in the variable service to be able to expose it as an environment variable.

```
- task: Bash@3
inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: |
           export cache=30
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=cache;]${cache}"
           export url={"https.8shd3dad#d/wipeout@doamin.com"}
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=url;]${url}"
           export Delay=10
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Delay;]${Delay}"
env:
   cache : $(30)
```

Comment: Hi @Vishnu Nandhan, I have tried as you suggested but I am not able to see it created

Comment: Are you trying to access the environment variable from a different job? I believe if you insert another script element in the same job and then you should see the environment variables.

Comment: Have a look at this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts to understand the scoping of variables